# concat function trim my variable

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query="update invoice set
invoice_no=CONCAT('W-',$id,'/1420')
where invoice_id=$id";
```

here $id=004 but every time it update as id=4 ,so my invoice_no become W-4/1420
whereas i want like this W-004/1420
can anybody help me to get rid of this problem

Comment: why don't you assign value to $id as a string? I mean, `$id = '004'`will definitely keep the value of $id as 004 while `$id = 004` actually means `$id = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

format it in your PHP code. Use `sprintf()` with format with leading zeros:

```
$query = sprintf('update invoice set 
                  invoice_no="W-%03d/1420" 
                  where invoice_id=%d', $id, $id );
```

or to avoid duplicating `$id` argument:

```
$query = sprintf('update invoice set 
                  invoice_no="W-%1$03d/1420" 
                  where invoice_id=%1$d', $id );
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a very good reason why you're not doing the `CONCAT()` using PHP? :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a number... concat will deal with it as an integer..
so try to concat it using php first, then pass it to your query:

```
$invoice_no = 'W-'.$id.'/1420';
$query="update invoice set
invoice_no='$invoice_no'
where invoice_id=$id";
```